# how to show same div with different heading by checkbox hide/show

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, checkbox

I want to display the same div with different heading by checkbox hide/show.

```js
$('#cbxShowHide').click(function() {
  this.checked ? $('#block').show(1000) : $('#block').hide(1000);
});
```

```css
#block {
  display: none;
  background: #eef;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="cbxShowHide" />
<label for="cbxShowHide">Show/Hide</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="cbxShowHide1" />
<label for="cbxShowHide1">Show/Hide1</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="cbxShowHide2" />
<label for="cbxShowHide2">Show/Hide2</label>
<div id="block">Some text here</div>
```

in the above example on clicking on checkbox "Show/Hide"I am able to display the text "Some text here".

I want to do this for nth checkbox so that I can show "some text here" nth time like "some text here1", "some text here2"

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do. Are you saying that you want to clone `#block` for each ticked checkbox, or amend it's text to match the labels of the checked boxes? An example of your expected output would help a lot here.

Comment: amend its text to match the labels of the checkboxes

Comment: i'm also ok with clone of #block for each ticked checkbox

Answer (score 0):

refer the [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ajays871/xs523nw8/). I have moved the content inside div in span

```
$('#cbxShowHide1').click(function(){
    $('#block span').text("yyour new text for this div")
    this.checked?$('#block').show(1000):$('#block').hide(1000);
});
```

Hope this helps

Comment: i want to display same div with different heading by multiple checkboxes

Comment: then this achieving what you have asked, clicking second checkbox changes the text of the div, simillarly you can write the code for third checkbox

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the click event only for a specific ID "cbxShowHide" 
I changed it so the event would be from all input which ever is clicked

```
$('[type~=checkbox]').click(function(){
    this.checked?$('#block').show(1000):$('#block').hide(1000);
});
```

```js
$('[type~=checkbox]').click(function(){
    this.checked?$('#block').show(1000):$('#block').hide(1000);
});
```

```css
#block{display:none;background:#eef;padding:10px;text-align:center;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="cbxShowHide"/><label for="cbxShowHide">Show/Hide</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="cbxShowHide1"/><label for="cbxShowHide">Show/Hide1</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="cbxShowHide2"/><label for="cbxShowHide">Show/Hide2</label>
<div id="block">Some text here</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing is that you need to use a class instead of an ID, then it will do that function for each individual checkbox,

Secondly remember that a for tag is specific to an ID so if you link an label to a checkbox make sure the two match.

Hope this example helps

```js
$('.checkbox').click(function(){
   if($(this).attr('id') == 'cbxShowHide')
   {
        $('#block').text('Some text here')
   }
   if($(this).attr('id') == 'cbxShowHide1')
   {
        $('#block').text('Some text here1')
   }
   if($(this).attr('id') == 'cbxShowHide2')
   {
        $('#block').text('Some text here2')
   }

    this.checked?$('#block').show(1000):$('#block').hide(1000);
});
```

```css
#block{display:none;background:#eef;padding:10px;text-align:center;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" class='checkbox' id="cbxShowHide"/><label for="cbxShowHide">Show/Hide</label>
<input type="checkbox" class='checkbox' id="cbxShowHide1"/><label for="cbxShowHide1">Show/Hide1</label>
<input type="checkbox" class='checkbox' id="cbxShowHide2"/><label for="cbxShowHide2">Show/Hide2</label>
<div id="block">Some text here</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**1. Toggling element's text**

**[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p6nve8x2/)**

*Case:* you want to just toggle the `#block` element text.
Fiddle uses `type='radio'` inputs rather than `type='checkbox'`, as you have only one place where you **toggle** text, so selecting only one option at the time is better way to do it.

**2. Showing elements based on checked checkboxes**

**[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8w3s2muu/)**

*Case:* you want multiple boxes hidden/shown based on checkbox input *state*(checked/unchecked).

On every *state* change, it loops through the checkboxes and:

- For every checked one, it selects box with the same number and **shows** it
- For every unchecked one, it select box with the same number and **hides** it

Answer (score 0):

Not so elegant, but i don't have much time..i hope i got what you meant

CSS

```
#block, #block1, #block2 {display:none;background:#eef;padding:10px;text-align:center;}
```

HTML

```
<input type="checkbox" id="cbxShowHide"/><label for="cbxShowHide">Show/Hide</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="cbxShowHide1"/><label for="cbxShowHide">Show/Hide1</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="cbxShowHide2"/><label for="cbxShowHide">Show/Hide2</label>
<div id="block"><span>Some text here</span></div>
<div id="block1"><span>Some text here 1</span></div>
<div id="block2"><span>Some text here 2</span></div>
```

JS

```
$('#cbxShowHide').click(function(){
    this.checked?$('#block').show(1000):$('#block').hide(1000);
});
$('#cbxShowHide1').click(function(){
    this.checked?$('#block1').show(1000):$('#block1').hide(1000);
});
$('#cbxShowHide2').click(function(){
    this.checked?$('#block2').show(1000):$('#block2').hide(1000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this Jsfiddle :[jsfiddle.net/xs523nw8/6/](https://jsfiddle.net/xs523nw8/6/)

```
   $("input[type='checkbox']").click(function(){
       if($(this).is(":checked")){
      $(this).siblings("input[type='checkbox']").removeAttr("checked");
      $("#block").text('Some Text Here :'+$(this).index());
      $("#block").show(1000)
    }
    else{
      $("#block").hide(1000);
    }
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/tz5ror3s/

I have added a class in checkboxes and bind click event on them and printing text inside block span.

```
$('.cbxShowHide').click(function() {
    $('#block span').text('Some text here ' + $(".cbxShowHide:checked").length );
    $('#block').show();
});
```